# Is there a simple way to create arrays from a string, that may have elements that are longer than others

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to say take
`"15+2+16\*9-2"`
and turn it into an array that looks like
`[15,"+",2,"+",16,"*",9,"-",2]`

I think it would be similar .toCharArray() but I am unsure what it would be.

The goal I am trying to accomplish is to have an array with all the numbers and operators and use that to calculate something, but I am also currently brainstorming other ways around it, I am just looking for something simple.

Comment: You can use [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) like: `yourstring.split(/(\W)/g);`

Comment: Do you have any more documentation on Regex, because I don't understand what that website is saying lol

Comment: @ZainWilson-WCHStudent you can try testing the query in regextester.com

Comment: So I would want to use my operators into it, but would it be something like```\+\-\*\/``` or something else?

Comment: what is the logic behind `\*` changed to `*` ?

Comment: a `*` starts italic formatting. to see a star, you need to escape it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply:

```js
const
    s1 = "15+2+16*9-2"
  , s2 = " 15 + 2 + 16 * 9 - 2 "
  , calcN = str => str.split(/(\+|\-|\*|\/)/).map(x=>isNaN(x)?x:Number(x))
  ;
console.log(JSON.stringify(calcN(s1))) // [15,"+",2,"+",16,"*",9,"-",2]
console.log(JSON.stringify(calcN(s2))) // [15,"+",2,"+",16,"*",9,"-",2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could match digits or no digits and map numbers if finite or strings.

```js
const
    string = "15+2+16*9-2",
    result = string
        .match(/\d+|\D+/g)
        .map(s => isFinite(s) ? +s : s);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Is there a way to make 'string' into a variable

Comment: `variable = 'string'` ...?

Comment: XD no I meant do something like ```const
string = variable``` in line 1-2 in your code sorry for not clarifying

Comment: you need not to get another variable, if you have already one. just take it.

Comment: Could I add a table or just a variable

Comment: When I add a table variable it says string.match is not a function

Comment: what is a table varaible. maybe you took an array it is the data structure with brackets, like `result` above.

Comment: Oh never mind I wouldn't need this now I just had to think harder

Answer (score 0):

```
splix = function ()
{
  u = [].slice.call(arguments); v = u.slice(1); u = u[0]; w = [u]; x = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < u.length; ++i)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < v.length; ++j)
    {
      if (u.slice(i, i + v[j].length) == v[j])
      {
        y = w[x].split(v[j]); w[x] = y[0]; w[++x] = y[1];
      };
    };
  };
  
  return w;
};
```

**Usage**: `splix(string, delimiters...)`

**Example**: `splix("1.23--4", ".", "--")`

**Returns**: `["1", "23", "4"]`

Comment: The sheer over complication of this made me laugh thank you. The single letter variable names are just a cherry on top.

I don't think the downvoters realize this is satire XD